# Woocommerce products in different database

Tags: database, woocommerce, product

is it possible to load Woocommerce products from different database?

Normally products are stored with wordpress posts, images etc in wp_posts and wp_postmeta, I'd like to separate products to another database.

Thank you for any hint!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is possible? Yes it is...

For that you will need to create an database for products with many columns like: name, price, variation, description...

When you do that, you need to change the woocommerce files for once the system process a new purchase, modify the stock, name of product,  description, also modify the other table, and that's not an easy task.

Now if you only want to get extract the time when products for other tables you could use the REST API woo commerce, it is returned with several keys and values of their products in JSON format, from there you can process them and insert one by one in your new table.